# In Joomla 2.5 how do I echo an article's "Link A" value in my template?

Tags: templates, joomla

I'm editing the layout of blog_item.php and I want to wrap an image with something like the following:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->params->get('link_A'); ?>"><img...
```

but I can't seem to find the correct syntax for accessing that value of the article's options. I've searched the non-helpful Joomla documentation and through google, but to no aveil.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've tried:

```
<?php echo $this->params->get('link_a'); ?>
<?php echo $this->params->get('link_A'); ?>
<?php echo $images->link_a; ?>
<?php echo $images->link_A; ?>
<?php echo $links->link_a; ?>
...etc, etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up I hope you're using [a template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) and not modifying the core file.

The items that are accessed in `blog_item.php` are stored in an array `$this->items`, each time the `tmpl` file `blog_item.php` is called the current item `$this->item` contains the current article object.

The URLs your looking for are in `$this->urls` which contains the data in a JSON format, the image data is contained in `$this->images` (also in a JSON format).

For example the data in images and urls might look like this:

```
$this->images =
{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}

$this->urls =
{"urla":"http:\/\/example.com","urlatext":"CPPL","targeta":"","urlb":"http:\/\/example2.com","urlbtext":"Home of Fine Joomla! Products","targetb":"","urlc":null,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}
```

To use them it's simply a matter of using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) like this:

```
$urls = json_decode($this->item->urls);
echo $urls->urla; 
echo $urls->urlatext;
```

Comment: Sweet! Yes, I'm using a template override. Thanks for the instruction. It worked with one little typo. In your final code you put jsondecode(... instead of json_decode(...