# Joomla Featured Image PHP Call

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm developing my templates for Joomla and I'm needing to get the URL of the 'Featured Image' of an article. Is there a special Joomla PHP call to get this as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, You cannot get this directly in the template's index.php file, but you can access it using the template's overrides. So start by creating a HTML folder within your template, then within that folder copy the folders you wish to override.

So for the image url, copy the following file
**components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php**
to 
**templates/yourtemplatename/html/com_content/article/default.php**
and then within that file you can access use / access the image url.

See more: [How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Comment: Template overrides is nothing to do with what the OP is asking for. They need to get the featured image URL, just like getting the current active menu ID or something

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is No, an Articles image and URL's values are part of the articles params and are stored as a JSON string. You can find more about accessing them in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332148/in-joomla-2-5-how-do-i-echo-an-articles-link-a-value-in-my-template/17342940#17342940)

The article content (or main component content) of a page in Joomla is displayed by the component, so to display the article content in a custom way a template needs to [create it's own overrides for each component or module](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) that it wants to change the appearance of. This is what [@mozami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158922/mozami) was talking about.

Comment: Does this mean that you cannot place the article's full text image, in a dedicated module position by using the template index.php file?